# Open Zeppelin PullPayment with web3

Tags: web3js, openzeppelin

I'm trying to make the user pay a certain amount of ETH with PullPayment.sol from Open Zeppelin.

It is suppose to :

- react to a button
- Open Metamask with the proper amount
- Make the payment happen

However metamask won't open, I get an error :

```
tutorialTokenInstance.asyncSend is not a function
```

I imported open zeppelin properly in my app folder, and I import in my contract

My code

```
handleTransfer: function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var amount = parseInt($('#TTTransferAmount').val());
var price = parseInt($('#TTPrice').val())

console.log('Transfer ' + amount);

var tutorialTokenInstance;

web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  var account = accounts[0];

  App.contracts.TutorialToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    tutorialTokenInstance = instance;
    var value = web3.toWei(price);
    var owner = tutorialTokenInstance.owner.call().then(console.log);

    return tutorialTokenInstance.asyncSend(owner, value)
```

My smart contract

```
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol';
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/payment/PullPayment.sol';

contract TutorialToken is StandardToken, Ownable, PullPayment {

    string public name = 'TutorialToken';
    string public symbol = 'TT';
    uint8 public decimals = 2;
    uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 12000;

    function TutorialToken() public {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    owner = msg.sender;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function asyncSend(address dest, uint256 amount) internal
```

This function has visibility set to `internal`. You cannot `asyncSend` <s>not from solidity</s> externally.

You should consider using code like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;


import "../payment/PullPayment.sol";


// mock class using PullPayment
contract PullPaymentMock is PullPayment {

  function PullPaymentMock() public payable { }

  // test helper function to call asyncSend
  function callSend(address dest, uint256 amount) public {
    asyncSend(dest, amount);
  }

}
```

As you can see this function has visibility set to `public` and you can call it from your js code (*obviously, you don't need this whole code that I provided, just add `function callSend()` to your contract*).

---

[Source](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/ec2f7ba8d1134c1f2fcd478137757cecac56579d/contracts/mocks/PullPaymentMock.sol)

Comment: Thanks I think I understood, but do you think that the logic behind my code is good ?

Comment: From quick overview everything looks fine. This line `owner = msg.sender;` can be removed, because owner is assigned on the initiation of  `Ownable` contract.

Comment: I have an issue, the console tells me that I have not enough arguments in my solidity function

Comment: If this answer solved your previous quesion please accept it. And if you have a new question please use [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Be sure to specify where the error occurs.